# Reading Int from User in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to read an input from the user. I'm pretty confident in my code, but for some reason I get a compile error every time. It says "28.8: Syntax error". From my testing, it's not so much that it has an issue with the syscall on line 28, but it's the very last line of the file (moving the data block to the bottom results in the error still taking place on the last line). I'm not really sure what's wrong and where to go from here.

```
.data
    prompt: .asciiz "Enter number: "
    message: .asciiz "\nYour number is: "

.text

main:
    #Ask for number
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt
    syscall

    #read number
    li $v0,5
    syscall

    #store number
    move $t0, $v0

    #display message
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, message
    syscall

    #print number
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t0
    syscall
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the error from this on MARS

Comment: Interesting. I'm using a Java-based MIPS compiler, so perhaps it's an issue with the compiler and not the code.

Comment: Or perhaps you have some unprintable character(s) in your source code file that got lost when you posted the code here.

Answer (score 0):

The error in your code may not be in line 28, but I think it is due to the lack of a termination code, i.e.

```
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

We generally use the termination code to exit a program. Not doing so might give an error like "Attempt to execute non-instruction at 0x00400058". Try putting that in at the end of your code to see if the error occurs again. I tried it on QtSpim and didn't encounter the error after adding the termination code.